# How to upload .hex file to Atmega8 Using Arduino IDE and Uno as an Isp?

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to upload an .hex file to an Atmega8 chip (SMD). I want to use the Arduino IDE and an Uno as the ISP program. But I'm unable to find any details on how to load a sketch which is in .hex format.

Following is the batch file I created to use with avrdude. I would like to know if the Command is correct?

```
C:\Users\Pranay\Desktop\DIY\arduino-1.0.1!\hardware\tools\avr\bin/avrdude -CC:\Users\Pranay\Desktop\DIY\arduino-1.0.1!\hardware\tools\avr\etc/avrdude.conf -v -v -v -v -patmega8 -cstk500
 -P\\.\COM4 -b19200 -Uflash:w:C:\Users\Pranay\Desktop\DIY\arduino-1.0.1!\hexFiles\Heart.hex:i

pause
```

Comment: It looks okay. Have you tried running it? It can't do any harm if it's wrong; you just get an error message.

Comment: When i run the batch file it says "C:\Users\Pranay " is not recognised as internal or external command, operable program or Batch file.

In the next line it says the system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: I think that means you got the file-path wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Gerben. figured out the mistake and finally sucedded in uploading sketch.

Comment: That good to hear. Could you share your solutions, so others might learn from it?

Comment: @Pranay Could you please post the solution as an answer to this post. https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/